# Kivy: 'name 'getValue' is not defined'

Tags: python, function, class, layout, kivy

So I made a little game that prints everything to the console which consists of some functions, a couple of lists and two extra text files with stats. The standalone game works fine, however, when I stick all the functions in a class and then call the class (so it works with the layout I made using Kivy), the error "name "getValue" is not defined" comes up.

I am confused because putting the functions into a class were the only change I have made. What did I miss?

I know that this would be very vague and unclear without the full code so here it is:

**original working file**

```
import time
import random
import os
import operator
import tkinter
import sys


homeIp = "1.1.1.1"
ipNum = homeIp
workingDir = "home/"
found = []
ports = {"ssh":[True,22],"sql":[True,1433],"http":[True,80],"ftp":[True,21]}
admin = True




def load(text,delay):
    print(text, end="")
    for x in range(0,delay-1):

        time.sleep(0.5)
        print(".", end="")
    print(".")

def createIpList():
    global found
    for x in range(0,random.randint(1,3)):
        found.append(str(random.randint(0,255))+"."+str(random.randint(0,255))+"."+str(random.randint(0,255))+"."+str(random.randint(0,255)))

def connect(ip):
    global ipNum
    load("trying to connect",8)
    if ip in found:
        print("connected to "+ip)
        ipNum = ip
        setPorts()
        createIpList()
        admin = False
    else:
        print("ip not found")

def scan():
    load("scanning for devices",6)
    for x in found:
        print(x)

def setPorts():
    ports["ssh"][0] = [random.choice([True,False])]
    ports["sql"][0] = [random.choice([True,False])]
    ports["http"][0] = [random.choice([True,False])]
    ports["ftp"][0] = [random.choice([True,False])]

def probe():
        print("SSH\t"+str(ports["ssh"][1])+"\t"+str(ports["ssh"][0]).strip("[").strip("]")+"\n"+
               "SQL\t"+str(ports["sql"][1])+"\t"+str(ports["sql"][0]).strip("[").strip("]")+"\n"+
               "HTTP\t"+str(ports["http"][1])+"\t"+str(ports["http"][0]).strip("[").strip("]")+"\n"+
               "FTP\t"+str(ports["ftp"][1])+"\t"+str(ports["ftp"][0]).strip("[").strip("]")+"\n"+
               "ALL PORTS MUST BE FALSE TO PORTHACK")

def shutDown():
    load("Shutting down ",4)
    quit()

def clearScreen():
    os.system('cls')

def giveHelp():
    print("COMMANDS :")
    for key in commands0:
        print(key)
    for key in commands1:
        print(key+" [ ]")

def openPort(portName,portNum):
    if portNum == ports[portName][1]:
        load("opening port "+str(portNum),10)

        ports[portName][0] = False
        print("port "+str(portNum)+" opened")
    else:
        print("Wrong port number")

def portHack():
    shut = False
    for port in ports:
        if str(ports[port][0])== "[True]":
            shut = True
    if shut == True:
        print("Can not operate port hack - all ports must be open")
    else:
        admin = True
        print("You are now system admin")

def inbox():
    file = open("emails.txt","r")
    for line in file:
        if line.strip()=="###EMAIL"+str(int(getValue("email")))+"###":
            ended = False
            for line in file:
                if line.strip()=="###EMAIL"+str(int(getValue("email"))+1)+"###":
                    ended = True
                if ended == False:
                    print(line)
    file.close()

def editValue(var,val):
    originalLines = []
    file = open("saveData.txt","r")
    for line in file:
        if len(line)>1:
            originalLines.append(line)
    file.close()
    for x in range(0,len(originalLines)):
        if originalLines[x].split("=")[0].strip()==var:
            newVal = (float(originalLines[x].split("=")[1].strip())+val)
            originalLines[x] = var+"="+str(newVal)
    file = open("saveData.txt","w")
    for item in originalLines:
        file.write(item+"\n")
    file.close
def reply():
    load("SENDING",3)

def getValue(var):
    file = open("saveData.txt","r")
    for line in file:
        if line.split("=")[0].strip() == var:
            return float(line.split("=")[1].strip())
    file.close()

def sysSpecs():
    print("CPU\t\t"+str(getValue("cpu"))+"GHz\n"+
           "RAM\t\t"+str(getValue("ram"))+"GB\n"+
           "PSU\t\t"+str(getValue("psu"))+"W\n"+
           "STORAGE\t\t"+str(getValue("storage"))+"GB")
    if getValue("gpu") == 0:
        print("GPU\t\tNONE")
    else:
        print("GPU\t\t"+str(getValue("gpu"))+"GHz")

def market():
    category = input("WELCOME TO AMAZING\n\nCategories\n->CPU\n->RAM\n->storage\n->PSU\n->GPU\n\n[Press ENTER to leave]\n")
    measurement={"CPU":"GHz","RAM":"GB","storage":"GB","PSU":"W","GPU":"GHz"}
    sortedParts = (sorted(parts[category].items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)))
    print("ITEM\t\t\t|"+measurement[category]+"\t|PRICE\n==================================")
    for item in sortedParts:
        if len(item[0])>=8:
            print(item[0]+"\t\t|"+str(item[1][0])+"\t|"+str(item[1][1]))
        else:
            print(item[0]+"\t\t\t|"+str(item[1][0])+"\t|"+str(item[1][1]))


def buy(item):
    exist = False
    itemCat = ""
    for category in parts:
        for part in parts[category]:
            if part == item:
                exist = True
                itemCat = category
    if exist == False:
        print("ITEM NOT IN STOCK")
    else:
        if parts[itemCat][item][1] <= getValue("money"):
            print("PURCHASED")
            editValue(itemCat.lower(),float(parts[itemCat][item][0])-getValue(itemCat.lower()))
        else:
            print("INSUFFICIENT BALANCE")

def balance():
    print(getValue("money"))

def eventCheck(command):
    if int(getValue("email")) == 0:
        inbox()
        editValue("email",1)
        inbox()
    if command[0] == "reply":
        if int(getValue("email")) == 1:
            editValue("email",1)
            inbox()
            print("$100 recieved")
            editValue("money",100)
        elif int(getValue("email")) == 3:
            if ipNum != homeIp:
                if admin == True:
                    print("CONGRATS")
    if int(getValue("email")) == 2:
        if getValue("cpu")>=1.5:
            editValue("email",1)


def main():
    command = input(ipNum+":"+workingDir+">").split(' ')
    try:
        if len(command) == 1:
            commands0[command[0]]()
        elif len(command) == 2:
            if command[0] == "sshCrack":
                commands1[command[0]]("ssh",int(command[1]))
            elif command[0] == "sqlInjection":
                commands1[command[0]]("sql",int(command[1]))
            elif command[0] == "webServerWorm":
                commands1[command[0]]("http",int(command[1]))
            elif command[0] == "ftpSpoof":
                commands1[command[0]]("ftp",int(command[1]))
            else:
                commands1[command[0]](command[1])
    except:
        print("",end="")
    eventCheck(command)


parts = {"CPU":{"LEG_1":[1.5,100],"LEG_2":[2,200],"AMP_Mk3":[2.5,300],"Inzel_Pontium":[3,500],"Inzel_Eye7":[3.5,700],"AMP_String_Cutter":[4,999]},
         "RAM":{"InsaneX_2":[2,40],"Revenger_4":[4,60],"InsaneX_8":[8,100],"Korsair_16":[16,160],"Z.SKILL_FORK":[32,400]},
         "storage":{"Sumsing_10":[10,20],"Queenston_50":[50,50],"EastDigital_100":[100,75],"SinDisk_250":[250,120],"CrazyX_500":[500,200],"Sumsing_TB":[1000,499]},
         "PSU":{"Korsair_Feather":[200,50],"Korsair_Beefy":[500,130],"Korsair_Ultra":[800,200]},
         "GPU":{"ZTX_1050":[2,100],"ZTX_1060":[4,200],"ZTX_1070":[8,400],"ZTX_1080":[16,800]}}
commands0 = {"scan":scan,"probe":probe,"shutdown":shutDown,"cls":clearScreen,"help":giveHelp,"portHack":portHack,"inbox":inbox,
             "reply":reply,"market":market,"sysSpecs":sysSpecs,"balance":balance}
commands1 = {"connect":connect,"sshCrack":openPort,"sqlInjection":openPort,"webServerWorm":openPort,"ftpSpoof":openPort,"buy":buy}
setPorts()
createIpList()
eventCheck([""])

while True:
    main()
```

**file where the only change is that all functions are put into a class which is then called:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
import time
import random
import os
import operator
import sys


homeIp = "1.1.1.1"
ipNum = homeIp
workingDir = "home/"
found = []
ports = {"ssh":[True,22],"sql":[True,1433],"http":[True,80],"ftp":[True,21]}
admin = True 
class MainWindow(BoxLayout):

    def load(text,delay):
        print(text, end="")
        for x in range(0,delay-1):

            time.sleep(0.5)
            print(".", end="")
        print(".")

    def createIpList():
        global found
        for x in range(0,random.randint(1,3)):
            found.append(str(random.randint(0,255))+"."+str(random.randint(0,255))+"."+str(random.randint(0,255))+"."+str(random.randint(0,255)))

    def connect(ip):
        global ipNum
        load("trying to connect",8)
        if ip in found:
            print("connected to "+ip)
            ipNum = ip
            setPorts()
            createIpList()
            admin = False
        else:
            print("ip not found")

    def scan():
        load("scanning for devices",6)
        for x in found:
            print(x)

    def setPorts():
        ports["ssh"][0] = [random.choice([True,False])]
        ports["sql"][0] = [random.choice([True,False])]
        ports["http"][0] = [random.choice([True,False])]
        ports["ftp"][0] = [random.choice([True,False])]

    def probe():
            print("SSH\t"+str(ports["ssh"][1])+"\t"+str(ports["ssh"][0]).strip("[").strip("]")+"\n"+
                   "SQL\t"+str(ports["sql"][1])+"\t"+str(ports["sql"][0]).strip("[").strip("]")+"\n"+
                   "HTTP\t"+str(ports["http"][1])+"\t"+str(ports["http"][0]).strip("[").strip("]")+"\n"+
                   "FTP\t"+str(ports["ftp"][1])+"\t"+str(ports["ftp"][0]).strip("[").strip("]")+"\n"+
                   "ALL PORTS MUST BE FALSE TO PORTHACK")

    def shutDown():
        load("Shutting down ",4)
        quit()

    def clearScreen():
        os.system('cls')

    def giveHelp():
        print("COMMANDS :")
        for key in commands0:
            print(key)
        for key in commands1:
            print(key+" [ ]")

    def openPort(portName,portNum):
        if portNum == ports[portName][1]:
            load("opening port "+str(portNum),10)

            ports[portName][0] = False
            print("port "+str(portNum)+" opened")
        else:
            print("Wrong port number")

    def portHack():
        shut = False
        for port in ports:
            if str(ports[port][0])== "[True]":
                shut = True
        if shut == True:
            print("Can not operate port hack - all ports must be open")
        else:
            admin = True
            print("You are now system admin")

    def inbox():
        file = open("emails.txt","r")
        for line in file:
            if line.strip()=="###EMAIL"+str(int(getValue("email")))+"###":
                ended = False
                for line in file:
                    if line.strip()=="###EMAIL"+str(int(getValue("email"))+1)+"###":
                        ended = True
                    if ended == False:
                        print(line)
        file.close()

    def editValue(var,val):
        originalLines = []
        file = open("saveData.txt","r")
        for line in file:
            if len(line)>1:
                originalLines.append(line)
        file.close()
        for x in range(0,len(originalLines)):
            if originalLines[x].split("=")[0].strip()==var:
                newVal = (float(originalLines[x].split("=")[1].strip())+val)
                originalLines[x] = var+"="+str(newVal)
        file = open("saveData.txt","w")
        for item in originalLines:
            file.write(item+"\n")
        file.close
    def reply():
        load("SENDING",3)

    def getValue(var):
        file = open("saveData.txt","r")
        for line in file:
            if line.split("=")[0].strip() == var:
                return float(line.split("=")[1].strip())
        file.close()

    def sysSpecs():
        print("CPU\t\t"+str(getValue("cpu"))+"GHz\n"+
               "RAM\t\t"+str(getValue("ram"))+"GB\n"+
               "PSU\t\t"+str(getValue("psu"))+"W\n"+
               "STORAGE\t\t"+str(getValue("storage"))+"GB")
        if getValue("gpu") == 0:
            print("GPU\t\tNONE")
        else:
            print("GPU\t\t"+str(getValue("gpu"))+"GHz")

    def market():
        category = input("WELCOME TO AMAZING\n\nCategories\n->CPU\n->RAM\n->storage\n->PSU\n->GPU\n\n[Press ENTER to leave]\n")
        measurement={"CPU":"GHz","RAM":"GB","storage":"GB","PSU":"W","GPU":"GHz"}
        sortedParts = (sorted(parts[category].items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)))
        print("ITEM\t\t\t|"+measurement[category]+"\t|PRICE\n==================================")
        for item in sortedParts:
            if len(item[0])>=8:
                print(item[0]+"\t\t|"+str(item[1][0])+"\t|"+str(item[1][1]))
            else:
                print(item[0]+"\t\t\t|"+str(item[1][0])+"\t|"+str(item[1][1]))


    def buy(item):
        exist = False
        itemCat = ""
        for category in parts:
            for part in parts[category]:
                if part == item:
                    exist = True
                    itemCat = category
        if exist == False:
            print("ITEM NOT IN STOCK")
        else:
            if parts[itemCat][item][1] <= getValue("money"):
                print("PURCHASED")
                editValue(itemCat.lower(),float(parts[itemCat][item][0])-getValue(itemCat.lower()))
            else:
                print("INSUFFICIENT BALANCE")

    def balance():
        print(getValue("money"))
    def getValue(var):
        file = open("saveData.txt","r")
        for line in file:
            if line.split("=")[0].strip() == var:
                return float(line.split("=")[1].strip())
        file.close()
    def eventCheck(command):
        if int(getValue("email")) == 0:
            inbox()
            editValue("email",1)
            inbox()
        if command[0] == "reply":
            if int(getValue("email")) == 1:
                editValue("email",1)
                inbox()
                print("$100 recieved")
                editValue("money",100)
            elif int(getValue("email")) == 3:
                if ipNum != homeIp:
                    if admin == True:
                        print("CONGRATS")
        if int(getValue("email")) == 2:
            if getValue("cpu")>=1.5:
                editValue("email",1)


    def main():
        command = input(ipNum+":"+workingDir+">").split(' ')
        try:
            if len(command) == 1:
                commands0[command[0]]()
            elif len(command) == 2:
                if command[0] == "sshCrack":
                    commands1[command[0]]("ssh",int(command[1]))
                elif command[0] == "sqlInjection":
                    commands1[command[0]]("sql",int(command[1]))
                elif command[0] == "webServerWorm":
                    commands1[command[0]]("http",int(command[1]))
                elif command[0] == "ftpSpoof":
                    commands1[command[0]]("ftp",int(command[1]))
                else:
                    commands1[command[0]](command[1])
        except:
            print("",end="")
        eventCheck(command)


    parts = {"CPU":{"LEG_1":[1.5,100],"LEG_2":[2,200],"AMP_Mk3":[2.5,300],"Inzel_Pontium":[3,500],"Inzel_Eye7":[3.5,700],"AMP_String_Cutter":[4,999]},
             "RAM":{"InsaneX_2":[2,40],"Revenger_4":[4,60],"InsaneX_8":[8,100],"Korsair_16":[16,160],"Z.SKILL_FORK":[32,400]},
             "storage":{"Sumsing_10":[10,20],"Queenston_50":[50,50],"EastDigital_100":[100,75],"SinDisk_250":[250,120],"CrazyX_500":[500,200],"Sumsing_TB":[1000,499]},
             "PSU":{"Korsair_Feather":[200,50],"Korsair_Beefy":[500,130],"Korsair_Ultra":[800,200]},
             "GPU":{"ZTX_1050":[2,100],"ZTX_1060":[4,200],"ZTX_1070":[8,400],"ZTX_1080":[16,800]}}
    commands0 = {"scan":scan,"probe":probe,"shutdown":shutDown,"cls":clearScreen,"help":giveHelp,"portHack":portHack,"inbox":inbox,
                 "reply":reply,"market":market,"sysSpecs":sysSpecs,"balance":balance}
    commands1 = {"connect":connect,"sshCrack":openPort,"sqlInjection":openPort,"webServerWorm":openPort,"ftpSpoof":openPort,"buy":buy}
    setPorts()
    createIpList()
    eventCheck([""])


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (1,1,1,1)
        return MainWindow()





if __name__ == '__main__':

    MainApp().run()
```

Just so you know, the whole point of putting it in a class is so I can use the layout I created using  the kv design language in a different piece of code. If it is necessary, I can post my .kv file that is opened by the program.

Comment: Declare the functions static or pass self as first argument. You cannot convert functions to class functions just by indenting.

Comment: @PriyankMehta Do I have to pass self for every function or is there a more efficient way?

Comment: @PriyankMehta I have not managed to do it. Declaring the function static causes a "staticmethod is not callable" error and I dont know how passing "self" would work for each individual function. Maybe I should try using modules?